# Column Value based on Referring Column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table which has a column named as last_update and another named as next_update where both are in the 'date' format. The problem now is how could I make the date value in the next_update is equal to the date value in the last_update plus a designed period for the same ID. I planned to program something like

```
value of column 'next_update' = value of column 'last_update' + designed period for the same ID
```

How could I program it in sql language for postgresql. Appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this "designed period" measured, in days?

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs ya in days.

Comment: You can just add the # of days (as an integer) to the 'last_update' Date value.

Comment: @m1Lb4nKs I planned to make it automatically update whenever I update the date in the column of last_update, how should I write it in the sql language,hmm

Comment: You have to something like set a trigger then, which is a separate question.

Comment: @green To update the column automatically you need a trigger, you can read more about how to create them in Postgresql here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET next_update = last_update + someInteger
```

See: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL#Because_the_difference_of_two_DATES_is_an_INTEGER.2C_this_difference_may_be_added.2C_subtracted.2C_divided.2C_multiplied.2C_or_even_modulo_.28.25.29

To do this for a specific row, you would simply do:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET next_update = last_update + someInteger
WHERE id = desiredID
```

Comment: how about for different row in the column, because sometime I just want to upgrade a specific row, thank you

Comment: See the edit. How will you be determining what row you want to update?

Comment: by selecting the item to be updated in a web interface, alright thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, but I mean how will you be uniquely identifying the row to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
update t
    set next_update = last_update + interval 'x' day;
```

Or if you want something variable:

```
update t
    set new_update = last_update + interval '1' day * x;
```

Where "x" can be another column or constant or `case` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will do?

```
update table1 set next_update = last_update + interval '1' day
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `next_update` column with value  `last_update` + n days, replace '1' with value n in the below query.

```
UPDATE A
SET  next_update = last_update + INTERVAL '1' day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much time you want to add, for example: + interval '1 hour'
You can find more at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html